# Azure Kubernetes Service: How to setup taint to whole node pool?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have one node pool named "**application pool**" which contains node vm size of **Standard_D2a_v4**. This node pool is set to "**Autoscaling**".
Is there in solution, where I taint the whole node pool in azure? to restrict the pods to schedule on that node pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provisioned your cluster with Terraform, you can specify `node_taints` in `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool` see [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster_node_pool) However, you can't add taints to default node pool

Comment: Yup. We can also set it up in ARM template also using ```node-taints``` But one once we set this to node pool we cannot remove it

Comment: @Kaivalya Isn't that what I have told you before? You haven't mentioned Terraform in your question.

Comment: @Wytrzymały Wiktor I want to say that we can set taints to whole node pool in AKS with using ```node-taints```. You can use it in ARM template or Terraform. But the problem here is once you set the node-taints then you cannot remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Taints can be setup with the `[--node-taints]` flag only when you are adding a node pool with [az aks nodepool add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/aks-preview/aks/nodepool?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_aks_preview_az_aks_nodepool_add) command:

> Add a node pool to the managed Kubernetes cluster.

```
az aks nodepool add --cluster-name
                    --name
                    --resource-group
                    [--node-taints]
```

However, you [cannot add taints to already existing node pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/aks-preview/aks/nodepool?view=azure-cli-latest):

> You can't change the node taints through CLI after the node pool is
> created.

A very similar topic is being discussed in [this open thread](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1402).

So currently it is not possible to set taints to an existing node pool on AKS. But you can set them up while adding a new node pool to the managed cluster.

Comment: Nop man..I successfully set taints to whole node pool in AKS. I have used the following command to set taint to whole node pool.

```az aks nodepool add --resource-group <resourceGroupName> --cluster-name <kubernetesClusterName> --name <spotNodePoolName> --priority Spot --eviction-policy Delete --spot-max-price -1 --enable-cluster-autoscaler --min-count 2 --max-count 6 --no-wait --node-vm-size Standard_D2a_v4 --node-taints agentpool=<spotNodePoolName>:NoSchedule ```

Comment: Yes...I get that. Thank you @Wytrzymały Wiktor for your response to my question.:)

Answer (score 2):

You can use below command for adding taint for existing nodepool in the **AKS** clusters:

```
az aks nodepool update --resource-group myResourceGroup --cluster-name myAKSCluste --name taintnp --node-taints sku=gpu:NoSchedule
```